# Tab jumps over [Save Edits] button

Tags: bug, help-improvement

When editing on the Help and Improvment queue you often end up with scrolling through one or more correctly formatted code blocks at the end of the text. If the title doesn't need changes, you now have to scroll all the way down to the preview text to get to the <kbd>Save Edits</kbd> button.

When you try to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> it jumps outside of the edit box to the link "Hide Preview" and from there to the link  "Cancel" next to "Save Edits".
Hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> twice should get you to save edits so you can press <kbd>Return</kbd> after that and carry on with up/down-voting the question.

This bug is particularly annoying when not using a scroll mouse (as when working on my laptop).